# How to use scss files globally?

Tags: angular

I've already read some topics here on the forum, but honestly I didn't find anything specific about my question.

I have several `.scss` files in my `/assets/scss` folder.

And these files are of different types, for example: `placeholders` and `mixins`.

Currently I give `@import` on these specific files, on the specific components which will use these files.

And this is getting a little weird, because I'm giving `@import` on several component `.scss`.

Is there any way I can use these without having to give `@import` on each `.scss`?

[image]

An example to which my project is currently:

```
@import '../../../assets/scss/mixins/breakpoints';

aside {
    @include breakpoint-desktop {
        width: 400px;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can import all your scss in the main style file generated by angular cli (styles.scss) but for any reason you need import sass code in specific component you can configure paths in your angular.json file to have a clean import using sass.

```
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths": [
   "src/assets"
 ]
}
```

## Now you can use the imports like that:

```
 @import 'placeholders/placeholder-1';
```

You can find more information [here](https://fireship.io/snippets/improving-long-relative-paths-imports/)

Comment: Thank you! I thought there was a way beyond doing what I said, not having to keep @import on each .scss file.